# Order Column in Power Pivot

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Every time I close and open the Power Pivot the order of columns changes Ex:

Order before close
Col1 / Col2 / Col3 / Col4

after closing the and opening sheet, I found the below order
Col3 / Col1 / Col4 / Col2

I want to know why this happened and, what is the solution method?

Comment: PowerPivot is a database. In databases, order of columns doesn't matter, because you refer to them by name, not by their place. Why do you need a solution? Why is the changing order a problem for you?

Comment: @RADO Thanks for your reply
I made many changes in the database by Dax and I need to order them to be able to see the data easier